# Long to HexString

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala snippet:

```
someLong.formatted("%016x")
```

As a result I receive the hex String.

However, I had to upgrade Scala version and now this line throws the following error:

```
 method formatted in class StringFormat is deprecated (since 2.12.16): Use formatString.format(value)` instead of `value.formatted(formatString)`, or use the `f""` string interpolator. In Java 15 and later, `formatted` resolves to the new method in String which has reversed parameters.
```

When I swap `formatString` with value, as the hint suggest, I got type mismatch.

How can I make it valid, either with the swap or f interpolation?

Comment: Please, can you put a complete example that demonstrates your problem? Because otherwise, this ("%016x".format(l)) works just fine.

Comment: It worked fine, but with the upgrade to the newer version I have stared getting the mentioned error. Hence the need for the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `f` interpolator is a good replacement and allows other text to be added easily:

```
f"$someLong%016x"

f"The result is 0x$someLong%016x"
```